# How to pass the image to servlet via ajax without using html forms?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, servlets

I have such html code

```
<input name="childLogin" type="text" placeholder="Login" id="login"/>
    <p class="validation" id="loginVal"></p>

    <input name="childPassword" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="password"/>
    <p class="validation" id="passVal"></p>


    <input name="childName" type="text" placeholder="Full name" id="fullName"/>
    <p class="validation" id="nameVal"></p>


    <p> Gender <select id="gender" name="gender">
        <option>
            Male
        </option>
        <option>
            Female
        </option>
    </select></p>


    <p>Select photo <input type="file" id="photo" name="photo" style="width:200px;border: none"/></p>
    <button  id="button">Add</button>
```

And some javascript code

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function () {


        var image = document.getElementById('photo').value;
        var gender = document.getElementById('gender').value;
       var log = document.getElementById('login').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
       var fullName = document.getElementById('fullName').value;
  $.ajax({
                method: "post",
                url: "http://localhost:8080/servlets.AddChildServlet",
                data: {login: log, password: password, fullName: fullName, gender: gender, image: image}
            })
                    .done(function (msg) {
                        alert(image);

                    });
```

How can I pass the image file to the servlet? And what should I write in my servlet to retrieve the image as inputStream?

Comment: your main question "via ajax without using html forms" don't match your code. With Javascript you access the html form fields and send the data to the server with ajax.

Comment: Maybe I don't express myself clearly. Do you have any ideas how can I pass the image file to servlet and retrieve  it to add to db?